# Mod_Rewrite "Replace" Tutorial

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, playframework-2.0

Given the following string as input:

```
/myproject/assets/%2Fmyproject-frontend%2Fstylesheets%2Fbase.css
```

How can I use mod_rewrite to achieve this as output:

```
/myproject/assets/myproject-frontend/stylesheets/base.css
```

**Note: There is a "/" and "%2F" right next to each other in the input string. If there is a way to use mod-rewrite to replace all instances of "%2F" with "/" and also fix the "//" at assets//myproject-frontend, then that would be the ideal solution.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's my WIP solution:

```
# If request is for something in "/myproject/assets/myproject-frontend/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myproject/assets/myproject-frontend/ [NC]
# input = /myproject/assets/%2Fmyproject-frontend%2Fstylesheets%2Fbase.css


# Replace all %2F with (single) forward slash
RewriteRule /([%2F]{3})/g \/ [N]
# output = /myproject/assets//myproject-frontend/stylesheets/base.css


# Replace all // with /
RewriteRule (\/\/) \/ [N] 
# output = /myproject/assets/myproject-frontend/stylesheets/base.css


# Take the cleaned up input and redirect to the correct URL
RewriteRule ^\/myproject\/assets\/(.*)$ \/myproject\/assets\/$1 [R=301,L]
# output = /myproject/assets/myproject-frontend/stylesheets/base.css
```